# Combining two hashmaps with the same key and same or different values

Tags: hashmap, java-7

I have two hashmaps that I need to merge.

```
MAP 1 - [[LOCATION: United Kingdom], [PERSON: Alfred Theodore MacConkey], [ORGANIZATION: Royal Commission, United]]

MAP 2 -{LOCATION=[United Kingdom], ORGANIZATION=[Royal Commission], PERSON=[Alfred Theodore MacConkey]}
```

If I create Map 3 and do an addAll() some values get overwritten. Like in case of ORGANIZATION I only get Royal Commission and United gets overwritten. I wrote a merge code for the two but get a null pointer exception. I just want to know if this approach is correct. I will debug and figure out why I am getting the exception.

```
public static  LinkedHashMap<String,Vector<String>> merge(HashMap<String, Vector<String>> a,  HashMap<String, Vector<String>> b) {
                   LinkedHashMap<String,Vector<String>> c = new  LinkedHashMap<String,Vector<String>>();


                   Set<Entry<String,Vector<String>>> entriesA = a.entrySet();
                   Set<Entry<String,Vector<String>>> entriesB = b.entrySet();

                    for (Map.Entry<String, Vector<String>> entry : entriesA ) {

                        Vector<String> aValues = a.get(entry.getValue());
                        String aKey =  entry.getKey();

                        Vector<String> allValues = entriesA.contains(aKey) ? a.get(aKey) : new Vector<String>();  
                        allValues.addAll(aValues);

                        c.put(aKey, allValues);

                    }



                    for (Map.Entry<String, Vector<String>> entry : entriesB ) {
                        Vector<String> bValues = b.get(entry.getValue());
                        String bKey =  entry.getKey();

                        if(c.containsKey(bKey) && c.get(bKey).equals(bValues) ) {
                            continue;
                            } 
                        else if(c.containsKey(bKey) && !(c.get(bKey).equals(bValues))) {
                            c.put(bKey, bValues); 
                      }
                    }
                    return c;
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
Vector<String> aValues = a.get(entry.getValue());
```

should be:

```
Vector<String> aValues = entry.getValue();
```

UPDATE:

Oh! and same goes for bValues

UPDATE 2:

Yet another issue: entriesA.contains(aKey) should be a.contains(aKey)

UPDATE 3:

Try something like this:

```
    LinkedHashMap<String, Vector<String>> c = new LinkedHashMap<String, Vector<String>>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, Vector<String>> entry : a.entrySet()) {
        Vector<String> aValues = entry.getValue();
        String aKey = entry.getKey();
        c.put(aKey, new Vector<String>(aValues));
    }
    for (Map.Entry<String, Vector<String>> entry : b.entrySet()) {
        Vector<String> bValues = entry.getValue();
        String bKey = entry.getKey();
        Vector<String> cValues = c.get(bKey);
        if (cValues == null) {
            c.put(bKey, new Vector<String>(bValues));
        } else {
            cValues.addAll(bValues);
        }
    }
    return c;
```

UPDATE 4:

To avoid duplicate values, replace line:

```
        cValues.addAll(bValues);
```

With:

```
Set<String> values = new HashSet<String>(cValues);
values.addAll(bValues);
cValues.clear();
cValues.addAll(values);
```

This will only deal with duplicates created by the merge though, not those that already existed.

Comment: Thanks! But this code doesn't seem to work. I got rid of the null pointer exception but the values still get overwritten.

Comment: before the first loop, c is empty, so, as the keys are all different, c cannot contain the current key, thus, no test needed.

Comment: Thank you!  One last help - is it possible for me to discard repeating values? This code gives me every value twice in my new c map.

Comment: @serendipity very easily: use Sets instead of Vectors (btw, the Vector class is deprecated)

Comment: I tried that but the output of this i.e C map is the input to another method which takes in a map of string and vector. So I am having an issue there. I tried to cast but apparently you can't cast a set to a vector.

Comment: Thank you! So very grateful!